# Is using nth Child selectors in jQuery dependent on browser support for CSS3?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Or is it safe to use when IE6/IE7 are heavily in use?

Comment: Yes, you can use it, It will work on IE6/IE7.

Answer (score 9):

The whole idea behind jQuery is that it normalizes behavior among browsers. Everything is supposed to work fine on any browser on [the "compatible" list](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility), which includes IE6 and upwards.

However, note that browsers may be added to or dropped from the compatible list in the future; for example, [jQuery 2.0 will only support IE 9 or later](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/).

Comment: Keep in mind though that this only applies to the documented methods. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

No, jQuery selector implementation does not depend on CSS3 support.

And yes, you can use all the jQuery features in IE6/7. jQuery works in IE 6.0+, FF 10+, Safari 5.0+, Opera, Chrome as stated on their site.